# Can I combine these two sql queries into one query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The first query is all the info that I need for companies within a 15 mile radius.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT CI.co,
                CI.name,
                CI.address1,
                CI.address2,
                CI.city,
                CI.state,
                CI.zip,
                CI.contact1,
                CI.contact1email,
                CI.contact2,
                CI.contact2email,
                CI.contact3,
                contact3email,
                Count(EI.id) AS ActiveEE
FROM   cinfo CI
       INNER JOIN einfo EI
               ON CI.co = EI.co
WHERE  NOT CI.co IN (SELECT co
                     FROM   scompanysetdetail
                     WHERE  companyset = 'REF-GCohen')
       AND enddate IS NULL
       AND EI.empstatus = 'A'
       AND CI.zip IN ( *zip codes for the 15 mile radius* )
GROUP  BY CI.co,
          CI.name,
          CI.address1,
          CI.address2,
          CI.city,
          CI.state,
          CI.zip,
          CI.contact1,
          CI.contact1email,
          CI.contact2,
          CI.contact2email,
          CI.contact3,
          CI.contact3email
```

The 2nd query gives me the top 10 paid employees by company

```
 WITH cterownum
     AS (SELECT co,
                id,
                ename,
                title,
                hiredate,
                salary,
                Dense_rank()
                  OVER(
                    partition BY co
                    ORDER BY salary DESC) AS RowNum
         FROM   cps_wss_emplist)
SELECT *
FROM   cterownum
WHERE  rownum <= 10
ORDER  BY co,
          rownum ASC
```

**How can I combine these two queries into one?**

Comment: Can you try using Code Sample function while you are using editor for sql queries (which looks like {} ), it makes it easier to read.

Comment: So, you want info from all companies within a 15 mile radius, and you want the top 10 employees from each company, all displayed in one result? That would be 10 rows for each company, repeating each company's info 10 times for each employee in the second query. Unless I'm misunderstanding you're request...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;WITH FirstCTE AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT CI.co,
            CI.name,
            CI.address1,
            CI.address2,
            CI.city,
            CI.state,
            CI.zip,
            CI.contact1,
            CI.contact1email,
            CI.contact2,
            CI.contact2email,
            CI.contact3,
            contact3email,
            Count(EI.id) AS ActiveEE
FROM   cinfo CI
   INNER JOIN einfo EI
           ON CI.co = EI.co
WHERE  NOT CI.co IN (SELECT co
                 FROM   scompanysetdetail
                 WHERE  companyset = 'REF-GCohen')
   AND enddate IS NULL
   AND EI.empstatus = 'A'
   AND CI.zip IN ( *zip codes for the 15 mile radius* )
GROUP  BY CI.co,
      CI.name,
      CI.address1,
      CI.address2,
      CI.city,
      CI.state,
      CI.zip,
      CI.contact1,
      CI.contact1email,
      CI.contact2,
      CI.contact2email,
      CI.contact3,
      CI.contact3email  
)
,
SecondCTE AS
(
SELECT co,
            id,
            ename,
            title,
            hiredate,
            salary,
            Dense_rank()
              OVER(
                partition BY co
                ORDER BY salary DESC) AS RowNum
     FROM   cps_wss_emplist
),
ThirdCTE AS
(
SELECT *
FROM   cterownum
WHERE  rownum <= 10
)
SELECT    *
FROM        FirstCTE F
               JOIN ThirdCTE C
                   ON F.Co = S.Co
```

Comment: this one seems to be the closest to what i'm looking to do but the ")" before the last SELECT is causing an error.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 93
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Hadn't notice your second CTE as i am on an iPhone. I updated my solution.

Comment: i appreciate the help. i get the following errors on this code

Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 96
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.


also it says the last 2 selects are invalid columns? am i missing something possibly?

Comment: I had left an ORDER BY in the thirdCTE which was your last SELECT

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
;WITH cterownum AS
(
    SELECT co
         , id
         , ename
         , title
         , hiredate
         , Salary
         , RowNum = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY co ORDER BY Salary DESC) 
    FROM cps_wss_emplist
)
SELECT  
      CI.*
    , EI.ActiveEE
    , ttt.*
FROM CInfo CI
JOIN (
    SELECT co, ActiveEE = COUNT(id)
    FROM EInfo
    WHERE empStatus = 'A'
    GROUP BY co
) EI ON CI.co = EI.co
JOIN cterownum ttt ON CI.co = ttt.co
WHERE NOT CI.co IN (
        SELECT co
        FROM SCompanySetDetail
        WHERE companySet = 'REF-GCohen'
    )
    AND EndDate IS NULL
    AND CI.zip IN ('')
    AND rownum <= 10
ORDER BY co, rownum
```

Comment: i get the following errors

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 29
Invalid column name 'empStatus'.
Msg 421, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.
Msg 421, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.
Msg 421, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The image data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.
Msg 421, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.

Answer (score 1):

For the easy way out, I'd just make both of those subqueries and join the results together, then list out all of the fields:

```
    Select -- list all your fields that exist in both temp tables

From
(
    SELECT DISTINCT CI.co,
        CI.name,
        CI.address1,
        CI.address2,
        CI.city,
        CI.state,
        CI.zip,
        CI.contact1,
        CI.contact1email,
        CI.contact2,
        CI.contact2email,
        CI.contact3,
        contact3email,
        Count(EI.id) AS ActiveEE
    FROM   cinfo CI
    INNER JOIN einfo EI ON CI.co = EI.co
    WHERE  NOT CI.co IN
    (
        SELECT co
        FROM   scompanysetdetail
        WHERE  companyset = 'REF-GCohen')
        AND enddate IS NULL
        AND EI.empstatus = 'A'
        AND CI.zip IN ( *zip codes for the 15 mile radius* )
    )
    GROUP  BY CI.co,
              CI.name,
              CI.address1,
              CI.address2,
              CI.city,
              CI.state,
              CI.zip,
              CI.contact1,
              CI.contact1email,
              CI.contact2,
              CI.contact2email,
              CI.contact3,
              CI.contact3email 
) a
Inner Join
(         
    ;WITH cterownum
         AS (SELECT co,
                    id,
                    ename,
                    title,
                    hiredate,
                    salary,
                    Dense_rank()
                      OVER(
                        partition BY co
                        ORDER BY salary DESC) AS RowNum
             FROM   cps_wss_emplist)
    SELECT *
    FROM   cterownum
    WHERE  rownum <= 10
    ORDER  BY co,
              rownum ASC
) b On b.co = a.co
```

Comment: added the semi-colon to the beginning. If that doesn't work, add something like "select blah where 1 = 0" and add a semicolon after that to break it up.

Comment: You can't write `WITH` inside sub-query blocks. Please see answers below.